# Python passing values between two methods

Tags: python, oop

I am having a hard time passing values from the format_column to the create_table methods:

```
class Sqlite_driver:

def __init__(self, db_name, table_name, columns):
    self.db_name = db_name
    self.table_name = table_name
    self.columns = columns


def format_column(self, columns):

    Sqlite_Allowed_Types = {
    "TEXT":"2500",
    "NUMERIC":"250",
    "INTEGER":"250",
    "REAL":"100",
    "BLOB":"100",}

    table_columns = []
    for k,v in columns.items():
        table_columns.append(k+" "+v+" "+"("+Sqlite_Allowed_Types [v]+")")
    return(table_columns)


def create_table(self,table_name, columns):
    '''
    creates the Sqlite3 table and columns.
    table_name expects a string
    columns expects a dictionary
    example :
    table_name = "Customer"
    columns ={"Name":"TEXT"} 


    '''

    format_column(columns)

    query = """CREATE TABLE """+ table_name+""" """+table_columns+""");"""
```

I think that is due to an instantiation issue but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually assign the return value to something in your `create_table` method after calling your `format_column` method

```
table_columns = self.format_column(columns)

query = """CREATE TABLE """+ table_name+""" """+table_columns+""");"""
```